# Use a guard clause instead of wrapping the code inside a conditional expression

Tags: ruby, rubocop

What is the best way to re-write the below code, in a way where rubocop doesn't treat it as a Style/GuardClause offense

```
    def abc(a1, a2, a3, a4)
      return some_method_call unless a1.is_a? Numeric
      unless a2.eql? 'name'
        some_method_call_1
      end
      unless a3.downcase.eql? 'age'
        some_method_call_2
      end
      unless a4 < 200
        some_method_call_3
      end
    end
```

Comment: You would be fine with that method if Rubocop wouldn't complain?

Comment: Depending on what `abc`, `a1`, `a2`, `some_method_call_1`, etc actually are, I bet you can probably write this cleaner and fix rubocop violations at the same time! You should view warnings like that as a canary, i.e. as an indicator that there's probably a slightly deeper design issue you could fix.

Comment: For example I would hazard a guess that `some_method_call_1` actually takes a parameter: `a2`, and that you could implement the method as: `def some_method_call_1(a2); return if a2 == 'name'; rest_of_method; end`

Comment: I personally do not like `unless` .. it causes too many headaches.   I'm toying with something like:   `a2.eql?('name') || some_method_call`  ... it lazy evaluates the method only if needed.

Comment: @DGM that reeks of control flow not sure logical conditional `||` makes sense here maybe lower level `or` but I figure rubocop would complain about that too

Comment: yeah, it's a bandaid on something that looks like a higher level problem.  "or"  would probably be more correct

Answer (score 3):

```
def foo
  return some_method_call unless a1.is_a? Numeric
  some_method_call_1 unless a2.eql? 'name'
  some_method_call_2 unless a3.casecmp?('age')
  some_method_call_3 unless a4 < 200
end
```

You could also replace the use of `downcase.eql?` for [`String#casecmp?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-casecmp-3F).

Note `String#casecmp?` is also available since Ruby 2.4.

Comment: In other words, exactly as the offense message suggests :)

Comment: I think you meant `String#casecmp?` (with a question mark). `String#casecmp` is not the same thing as `downcase.eql?`. e.g. `"AGE".casecmp('nope') #=> -1`

Answer (score 0):

I'm making an assumption that the guard conditions will always apply to particular methods being called.

If that is the case, you can extract the guard conditions out into the specific methods being called and explicitly pass in the variable being checked.

Granted, this is more verbose, but I would argue that it makes all the methods more usable, subclassable, overridable, etc.  You get more control over the functionality of your method. And it's easier to read.

```
def abc(a1, a2, a3, a4)
  if a1.is_a?(Numeric)
    do_something_with_values(a2, a3, a4)
  else
    some_method_call
  end
end

def do_something_with_values(a1, a2, a3)
  some_method_call_1(a1)
  some_method_call_2(a2)
  some_method_call_3(a3)
end

def some_method_call_1(a)
  return if a.eql?('name')
  # some functionality
end

def some_method_call_2(a)
  return if a.downcase.eql?('age')
  # some functionality
end

def some_method_call_3(a)
  return if a < 200
  # some functionality
end
```

**Edit:**

Comparing my code to the *good* examples in the [RuboCop GuardClause docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/GuardClause), they seem to match in style.
I'm not entirely clear if my rewrite of `abc` matches the RuboCop style, but I can't think of any reason why it would be considered bad.

Answer (score 0):

I think what Rubocop wants here is something like:

```
def abc(a1, a2, a3, a4)
  return some_method_call unless a1.is_a? Numeric
  unless a2.eql? 'name'
    some_method_call_1
  end
  unless a3.downcase.eql? 'age'
    some_method_call_2
  end
  return unless a4 < 200
  some_method_call_3
end
```

This is because the last method is only called when the `a4 < 200` condition is met. So it thinks you could just as well exit early.

Rubocop does not complain about this:

```
def abc(a1, a2, a3, a4)
  return some_method_call unless a1.is_a? Numeric
  some_method_call_1 unless a2.eql? 'name'
  some_method_call_2 unless a3.casecmp('age').zero?
  some_method_call_3 unless a4 < 200
end
```